# How to find the execution time of the below mentioned algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Suppose the running time of a Module A is a constant M and N is the size of the input data.

```
1. Set J:=N.
2. Repeat Steps 3 and 4 while J>1.
3.   Module A.
4.   Set J:=J/2.
     [End of Step 2 loop.]
5. Return.
```

Comment: `O(log(n))`, dividing by two iteratively is a `log` (extracting bits of binary representation)

Comment: @J-BYunès  Glop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The time complexity of this algorithm is in **O(log(n))**

## Explanation

- Since **Module A** runs in a constant time M, we can say that its running time is **O(1)**
- Same goes for the instruction `Set J:=J/2`, it runs in **O(1)**
- Let's say that the loop at line 2 runs **K** times in total. So after the loop has finished iterating K times, we will end up with **J = 1**.

  - After the 1st iteration of the loop, we have **N / 2** iterations left. After the 2nd we have **N / 4**. The 3rd **N / 8**, the 4th **N / 16**, and so on.
  - After **K** iterations (when the loop is done iterating) we will end up with **J = 1 = N / (2^K)**.
  - So **N / (2^K) = 1**, which gives us **N = 2^K**. Therefore the number of iterations is **K = log2(N)**
- The instructions at each iteration of the loop take **O(1)**, we end up with a total of **O(log(N))**

## Notes

- Here is an [article](https://hackernoon.com/what-does-the-time-complexity-o-log-n-actually-mean-45f94bb5bfbf) that illustrates the concept by using it in the [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: I think the last note does not make much sense, since `N` is *not* the input itself, it is the *size* of the input, so an *integer*.

Comment: Yep you're right. Mixed up the _set data structure_ with the _set operation_ (assign). I edited the answer to clarify and remove the last note. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given dividing a number by two can be done in constant time, the time complexity of this algorithm is *O(log N)*. For (very) large numbers, dividing by two however takes some extra time: *O(log K)* with *K* the value to divide.

The algorithm stops when `J` is less than or equal to one. So that means that if `J=2`, then it will take *M+1* steps (the time evaluate the module, and one to divide `J` by two, let us here assume that dividing by two takes constant time).

Now for `J=2*K` (with `K` a variable), it takes again *M+1* steps to complete the loop, plus the time it takes with `J=K` to solve the problem.

So that means that we obtain the following equation:

```
T(1) = 0
T(N) = T(N/2) + M + 1
```

We see thus that the amount of work grows linear in the number of *iterations*, and the number of iterations has an upperbound *log<sub>2</sub> N*: if we have to perform *K* steps, then the initial *N* is between *2<sup>K-1</sup>+1* and *2<sup>K</sup>*.

So that means that the total number of steps is bounded by:

```
T(N) = (M+1) * log2(N)
```

`M` is constant, so that means that `M+1` is constant, hence the *variable* part is `log2(N)`. This is an *O(log N)*.

Strictly speaking however if *N* can be very large, such that we need an arbitrary amount of memory, then division is not constant. If we use a binary number system, we can shift the bits in *O(log K)* with *K* the number to divide by two (and *log<sub>2</sub> k* the number of bits).

In that case a step thus takes:

```
T(1) = 0
T(N) = T(N/2) + M + log2(N)
```

With `K` iterations, the number of steps is bounded by:

```
 K
---
\
/    log2(I) + M
---
I=1
```

The sum of *log<sub>2</sub>(i)* with *i* from *1* to *k* is equal to *log<sub>2</sub>(k!)*, which has as upperbound *O(k log k)*. Since the number of steps *k* is bound by *O(log N)*, this thus means that the the total time complexity of the divisions is *O(log N × log(log N))*. The total time complexity of all calls to the module remain *O(M×log N)* so *O(log N)*, so the time complexity is *O(log N × (1+log(log N)))*, or simpler *O(log N + log N×log(log N))*.

It is however possible to slightly change the algorithm such that we do not have to perform these divisions *explicitly*: we can use some sort of cursor that each time moves one step further until *N* is "exhausted", in which case the time complexity is again *O(log N)*.